# Ruby nomethoderror "each" for nil class

Tags: ruby

I have some code which returns the error and i cannot understand why. I am abit of a newbie with Ruby but feel I am getting there:

```
line 27: NoMethodError "each" for NilClass
```

The code I am using is below:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'sqlite3'

FIELDS = [['cityselect', 'VARCHAR'],['match', 'VARCHAR'], ['num_phone', 'NUMERIC'], ['name', 'VARCHAR'],['address', 'VARCHAR'] ]

DIV_ID = "#dgrSearch" 
FILE_O = File.open('hold-data/directory-tel.txt', 'w')
FILE_O.puts( FIELDS.map{|f| f[0]}.join("\t") )

DB_NAME = "hold-data/directory-tel.sqlite"
File.delete(DB_NAME) if File.exists?DB_NAME
DATAB = SQLite3:Database.new( DB_NAME )

TABLE = "records_telephone"
DB_INSERT_STATEMENT = "INSERT into #{TABLE} values
(#{FIELDS.map{'?'}.join(',')})"

DATAB.execute "CREATE TABLE #{TABLE}(#{FIELDS.map{|f| "`#{f[0]}` #{f[1]}"}.join(', ')});"
FIELDS.each do |fn| 
DATAB.execute "CREATE INDEX #{fn[2]} ON #{TABLE}(#{fn[0]})" unless fn[2].nil?
end

Dir.glob("hold-data/pages/*.html").reject{|f| f =~ /All match/}.each do |fname|
meta_stuff = File.basename(fname, '.html').split('--')
page = Nokogiri::HTML(open(fname))

page.css("#{DIV_ID} tr")[1..-2].each do |tr| # this is line #27
data_tds = tr.css('td').map{ |td| 
td.text.gsub(/[$,](?=\d)/, '').gsub(/\302\240|\s/, ' ').strip
}

row_data = meta_stuff + data_tds
FILE_O.puts( data_row.join("\t")) 
DATAB.execute(DB_INSERT_STATEMENT, row_data)

end 
end

FILE_O.close
```

Can anybody see what I have done wrong?

Comment: Hi Suzie, welcome to the site. You would get answers if you localize the problem a bit yourself first rather than dumping all your code here. There's probably a line number that accompanies your error message, and that could help us understand your problem better. You could also explain what you are trying to accomplish with this code and what kind of input it is getting.

Comment: hi ye please see comments in answer below. Error says line 27. thanks will remember in future and post less code too :)

Comment: I edited your question to indicate the line number, you can also always edit your own questions and answers to make them better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be useful next time if you tell us **which line** the error occurs on.

From the looks of it theres only 1 line here where the expression your calling `each` on might return **nil**:

```
page.css("#{DIV_ID} tr")[1..-2].each do
```

Remember `the_array[1..-2]` will return **nil** if `the_array` is **empty**.

So `page.css("#{DIV_ID} tr")` might return an empty array hence the error.

If this behavior is not expiected I would consider invesigating why this is happening OR maybe **check whether the array is empty before** calling  `[1..-2]` on it (see below). Just a suggestion.

```
if page.css("#{DIV_ID} tr").empty?
   #empty array
else
   #not empty
end
```

Comment: i added an if before the page.css and that seems to have fixed it. Thanks and sorry did not post line number